# Random polygon color with rule based styling

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, print-composer

I am using a rule based styling only to show certain polygon which match with below filter:

```
"NAME_2"  = 'Probolinggo' OR "NAME_2"  = 'Kota Probolinggo'
```

The layer has thousands of polygon, so I need to filter only to show certain polygon with above filter rule.

But I want the displayed polygon to have random color on it just like when we do on "categorized style".
Is it possible?

[image]

so basically i just want to display random color on yellow line polygon which filtered based on using "rule-based" styling

[image]

the yellow line polygin supposed to consist thousands of polygon, but i filtered out just to show up on certain area.
so it will looked like this

[image]

Comment: Categorized symbols don't have random colours, they have colour based on the category they are in. Please specify what you want to achieve.

Comment: hi @Erik thank you for respond, i edit the question to make it more clearer to understand.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make anything clearer. Can you provide an example of how the map should look like?

Comment: sorry to make you confuse, i edited again the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to do what you need depending on you environment and limitations.

I think the most straightforward one would be:

Possible solution 1:
Use your formula in the filter option (right click on the layer/filter..) instead of in the styling, then you will be able to use the categorized styling the way you are used to.

Other solutions may include:

- Use the categorized random styling on you layer and remove all the other categories manually
- extract the features you want to visualize and then apply styling
  ...

Comment: you're definitely answer my question. than you Geotyr

Answer (score 0):

You can go under categorized symbols, and use something like that:

```
CASE
WHEN "NAME_2" IN ('Probolinggo', 'Kota Probolinggo') THEN $id
END
```

And then you just need to uncheck "all other value".

Answer (score 0):

You can use rule based and then use "refine" in the bottom left corner for each rule (se picture below though it´s in Swedish). Then it´s a simple matter och choosing a unique data field like ID and classify. All random colors assigned to each ID will appear under the main color for the rule and these sub-colors will be rendered instead of the rules main color. The randomized colors are permanent categories and won´t change with changed data (I think) and you can add or subtract colors/sub categories with the plus and minus sign. I have a project where I know I had done this but I could not remember how. So, I spent like 3 hours figuring out again...

[image]

[image]